# compile error when a template function call a template static function in a template class

Tags: c++11, templates

A compile error when I write template in c++, hard to understand for me. This is the code

```
template<typename T>
struct S
{
    template<typename U>
    static void fun()
    {
    }
};

template<typename T>
void f()
{
    S<T>::fun<int>(); //compile error, excepted primary expression before `int`
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `template`

```
S<T>::template fun<int>();
      ^^^
```

to tell the compiler that `<` between `fun` and `int` is the beginning of template arguments list. Otherwise, it will be interpreted as the `<` (i.e., *less-than*) operator.